# Bash script - How to skip pictures that are already in the folder?

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script that uses ImageMagick to make thumbnail pictures from folder **/pictures/** and puts them to folder **/thumbnails/**:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /pictures/
for pic in *.jpg;
do
    convert $pic -strip -quality 80 -thumbnail 225x150 /thumbnails/$pic;
done
```

But I would like that script to skip pictures that are already in **/thumbnails/** folder. How could I do that?

Comment: You could add `if [ -e /thumbnails/$pic ]` around the convert command.

Comment: The world needs more Makefiles.

Comment: Right up until you modify one of the source images. *runs*

Comment: Do you really want your `pictures` and `thumbnails` directories under the root directory?

Comment: Keith, that's just example folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /pictures/
for pic in *.jpg;
do
    if [ ! -f /thumbnails/$pic ]; then
        convert $pic -strip -quality 80 -thumbnail 225x150 /thumbnails/$pic;
    fi
done
```

In the `if` statement, the `-f` flag checks for the existence of the file, and the `!` negates the condition.  So altogether, the `if` statement verifies that the file doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3):

Since the world needs more Makefiles, put the following into a file called `Makefile`, where "↹" is a literal tab character:

```
SRC := /pictures/
DEST := /thumbnails/
PICTURES := $(wildcard $(SRC)*.jpg)
THUMBNAILS := $(patsubst $(SRC)%,$(DEST)%,$(PICTURES))

thumbnails: $(THUMBNAILS)

$(DEST)%.jpg: $(SRC)%.jpg
↹convert $< -strip -quality 80 -thumbnail 225x150 $@
```

You can then invoke it as:

```
make thumbnails
```

And if you want it to use more than one core you can tell it to do so with the `-j` flag.

```
make -j4 thumbnails
```